# Windows 10 & 8 toast notification for windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, toast

I'm doing a chat application for the company. I created the application with c # windows form app windows 10 's toast notification required for me. I enter code here am write some code but does not display notification code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1 
{
  public partial class Form1: Form 
  {
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern void SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string AppID);
    private const String APP_ID = "Microsoft.Samples.WindowsFormsApp1";

    public Form1() 
    {
        SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(APP_ID);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        GenerateToast("Titleee", "Contenttt");
    }

    public void GenerateToast(string header, string content) 
    {
        ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02;
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
        XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(header));
        toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(content));

        XmlNodeList toastImageElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        ((XmlElement) toastImageElements[0]).SetAttribute("src", "Resources\\Pixelkit-Flat-Jewels-Chat.ico");

        IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        ((XmlElement) toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

        try 
        {
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(APP_ID).Show(toast);

        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
     }
  }
}
```

no notification appears
please help me

Comment: please properly format your post and code ;)

Comment: can you make an example for me please

Comment: it has been edited by someone already